# Reload form after success callback

Tags: jquery, refresh

I have a profile editing form with multiple file input (image), I wanted to refresh the form and fetch/show the latest updated data (image) back to the same form upon on success callback without whole page refresh.

```
$("#mylisting_form").ajaxForm({
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
            var btn = $('#btn_mylisting');
            btn.button('loading')
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        console.log(percentComplete); // Show the completed percent 
    },
    success: function(response) {

        if(response.success == 'success'){
            $('#form').reset();
            $('#successful').html('<b>Edited saved!</b>').show();

        }else{
            $('[id$="_error"]').html('');
            $.each(response.error, function(key, value){
                if(value){
                    $('#' + key + '_error').html(value);
                }
            });
        }
        $('#btn_mylisting').button('reset');
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown );
    }

}); 

//form
<div id="form">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" id="mylisting_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="inc/callback/request_update_item.php">

                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $data->user_id ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="<?php echo $list_id ?>">

                    //uploaded image will show here
                    <div id="show_images"><? php fetch image goes here ?></div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="photo">Photo</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="file" name="files[]" class="multi" accept="gif|jpg" maxlength="3" /><p class="help-block">Up to 3 photos max.</p></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="publish"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="checkbox" name="publish" <?php echo $checked ?>> Publish</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="email">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $list->name ?>"><span class="error" id="name_error"></span></div>
                    </div>

                    <hr />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-7"><button class="btn btn-success" id="btn_mylisting" type="submit" data-loading-text="Loading...">Save</button></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
</div>
```

Ajax request (request_update_item.php) only callback success or error state, it will not get the post data back to response, I was think simple, that is reason why I am asking is that possible to just refresh a whole `div` or `form` just for particular item to show updated info which is fetch from database.

Thanks for the advise!

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. Which image are you talking about???

Comment: the form has multiple files upload (image), once the form data success process in database, the callback will reload the form to get/show the uploaded files (image) back to the same form without whole page reload, hope you can get what I means. thanks!

Comment: You should really provide more relevant code as when/how do you call the ajax request? How do you target/get source of new specific image? What about relevant HTML code? Etc...

Comment: Well so you are using PHP to update new images. You should really have told us about that before... Now, indeed, you should return new image source from ajax request and then append it to the specific DIV. PHP is a server side script, you can't recall it after page is rendered without refreshing all the page, meaning, requesting again the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the html first then show it:

```
$('#successful').html('<b>Edited saved!</b>').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could'nt you use a template javascript framework like Mustache or Handlebars, in order to rebuild dynamically your form ?

What is exactly your image about ?

Comment: just few images to show after success callback in a same form, i knew it could done but refreshing the whole page but its meaningless to use ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but...

```
$('#form').reset();
```